# Querying Multiple foreign key relationships in DRF

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am completely new to django and python kindly help me with below query:

I have 3 models , with multiple foreign key relations with given sample data

now I need 3 outputs via django ORM  or Serializers

1. for a given student id ,display the Student details and marks in each subjects
2. list all the students with their total marks (sum of three subjects in this case)
3. Average marks scored by all the students for each subject for ex as per the given sample marks in English are 65 , 95 and average is 80

   ```
   { Subject: "English", average: " 80" }
   ```

```
class Student(models.Model):
        student_id = ShortUUIDField(primary_key=True, editable=False)
        first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
        last_name  = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Subjects(models.Model):
    subject_code = ShortUUIDField(primary_key=True, editable=False)
    subject_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Reports(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(Student,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='student_report')
    subject = models.ForeignKey(Subjects,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='subject',default=None)
    marks   = models.IntegerField(max_length='3')
class Meta:
    unique_together = ("student", "subject")
```

sample data

```
Student data

student_id  first_name  last_name
  1            abc        x
  2            def        y
 


Subjects data

subject_code  subject_name
    1          English
    2          Science
    3          Math


Reports data

 student_id  subject_id  marks 
     1          1         65
     1          2         75
     1          3         92
     2          1         95
     2          2         85
     2          3         62
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably need to modify your models, serializers etc. like below.

**2. list all the students with their total marks (sum of three subjects in this case)**

Solution: You can calculate the total marks for each student by defining a function in your "Student model" to calculate the total marks and using "@property" decorator so that you can access that function as a property like any other model property. So, your model would be like defined below.

```
class Student(models.Model):
    student_id = ShortUUIDField(primary_key=True, editable=False)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name  = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    
    @property
    def total_marks(self):
        reports = self.student_report.all()
        total_marks = sum([report.marks for report in reports])
        return total_marks
```

To access this "total_marks" property each time your "Student" serializer is called you'll modify your "Student" serializer like below.

```
class StudentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = Student
    fields = ["student_id", "first_name", "last_name", "total_marks"]
```

**1. for a given student id, display the Student details and marks in each subjects**

Solution: To achieve this you'll again need to modify your "Student" serializer like below:

```
class ReportsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = Reports
    fields = "__all__"

class StudentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
student_report = ReportsSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

class Meta:
    model = Student
    fields = ["student_id", "first_name", "last_name", "total_marks", "student_report"]
```

**3. Average marks scored by all the students for each subject for ex as per the given sample marks in English are 65 , 95 and average is 80**

Solution: You'll need to modify your "Subjects" model in the same way we modified the "Student" model to get "total_marks" only difference being we'll be calculating the "average" here.

```
class Subjects(models.Model):
    subject_code = ShortUUIDField(primary_key=True, editable=False)
    subject_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    @property
    def average(self):
        reports = self.subject.all()
        total_marks = sum([report.marks for report in reports])
        average_marks = total_marks / len(reports)
        return average_marks
```

To access this "average" property each time your "Subjects" serializer is called you'll modify your "Subjects" serializer like below.

```
class SubjectsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = Subjects
    fields = ["subject_code", "subject_name", "average"]
```